# What's wrong in "Watt"/("Centimeters")^2

Tags: units

Why Mathematica returns the following input unevaluated?

```
Quantity[1.3 10^17, "Watt"/("Centimeters")^2]

Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification (Watt)/(Centimeters)^2. >>
```

`"Watt"/("Centimeters")^2` is quite legal unit. It is a measure of energy flux density.

Comment: It's "Watts", not "Watt".

Comment: When having problems with `Quantity` use `WolframAlpha` to determine correct specification for quantities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Quantity[1, "Watts"/"Centimeters"^2]
```

returns

$\qquad$[image]

when evaluated by Mathematica 10.

(One would think that the `Quantity` function had more flexibility than that)

Comment: To get the strings colored, don't use back-ticks, but indent four spaces. I made the edit.

Answer (score 9):

This is an addendum to John Conor Cosnett's answer.

There is a degree of flexibility as long as you enter your unit expression as a single string. Thus,

```
Quantity[1.3 10^17, "Watt/Centimeters^2"]
Quantity[1.3 10^17, "Watts/Centimeter^2"]
Quantity[1.3 10^17, "Watt/Centimeter^2"]
Quantity[1.3*10^17, "W/cm^2"]
```

all work and give

> ```
> Quantity[1.3*^17, "Watts"/"Centimeters"^2]
> ```

But if you enter units as an arithmetic expression, you must use the correct canonical names.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg. Could you please tell me how to change the colour of the strings in my code to red like yours? `"Watt/Centimeters^2"`